# How to hide items before filtering in django templates?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

i have a simple website and i want to test the filters but i have a problem ! i don't want user to see all results i want him to see only the filtered one before start filtering or searching and here is my CODE

```
(views.py) 

 def Home(request):    
        mobile_filter=MobileFilter(data=request.GET,queryset=MyMobile.objects.all())
        my_phone = mobile_filter.qs
        context={"myphone":my_phone,"myfilter":mobile_filter}
        return render(request,"mobile_home.html",context)
```

(html)

```html
{% for obj in myphone %}

          
           {{obj.name}}
            {{obj.code}}
            {{obj.date}}
            {{obj.place}}
            {{obj.type}}
            {{obj.mobile}}

         
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It is not entirely clear to me what you want to achieve?

Comment: i have a list of so many items in database and i want to show only filterd items not all of them
and this loop shows all of them on the main page

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
def Home(request):
    mobile_filter = MobileFilter(data=request.GET,queryset=MyMobile.objects.all())
    if all(v == '' for v in request.GET.values()):
        # all empty
        my_phone = []
    else:
        my_phone = mobile_filter.qs
    context = {"myphone": my_phone, "myfilter": mobile_filter}
    return render(request, "mobile_home.html", context)
```